# Como substituir a extensão mas permanecer o título

Tags: javascript, regex, extensão, ancora

Tenho uma pasta, na qual abrange vários vídeos com nomes iguais e formatos diferentes:

https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/monstros_sa_2.webm

https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/monstros_sa_2.mp4

https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/big_buck_bunny.webm

https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/big_buck_bunny.mp4

E assim por diante ...

---

Como vou dar duas opções de download, para os visitantes. Tenho que alterar uma delas. Veja:

```js
function baixar(arquivo) {

    var get = document.getElementById("download").getElementsByTagName('a');

  for(var i in get) {
       get[i].href = arquivo; 
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/monstros_sa_2.webm" onclick="baixar(this); return false">A</a>
<a href="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/madagascar_2.webm" onclick="baixar(this); return false">B</a>
<a href="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/big_buck_bunny.webm" onclick="baixar(this); return false">C</a>
<a href="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/procurando_dory.webm" onclick="baixar(this); return false">D</a>

    <hr>

    <span id="download">
        <a id='mp4'>MP4</a> &nbsp; | &nbsp; <a id='webm'>WEBM</a>
    </span>
```

> Como podemos observar, todos os links no documento HTML são de natureza `*.webm`.
>
> O que falta é efetuar a troca de `*.webm` por `*.mp4`, para o link `<a id='mp4'>MP4</a>`.

Pensei em trabalhar com `RegExp`, uma coisa que ainda não consigo elaborar.

Alguém tem uma lógica a me mostrar de como posso contornar este empecilho?

Comment: `seuLink.replace('.webm', '.mp4');`

Comment: @andrepaulo Huuummm! verdade nem me lembrava desta função no momento que você me trouxe a frente a lembrança. Vou testa-lá e jaja volto pra confimar se funcionou corretamente para o propósito. =)

Comment: eu nao entendi quando voce vai usar Mp4 e quando vai usar o WEBM... nessa hora que voce converte o nome ... supondo que voce tenha dois links.. um pra WEBM e uma pra MP4... no de mp4 voce tem que rodar um metodo que pega o link e troca pra .mp4 .. ja que o mesmo esta vindo com o .webm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Há um problema em usar [.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) assim:

```
str.replace(".webm", ".mp4");
```

O que acontece se `location` tiver `".webm"` no meio da cadeia em vez de como uma extensão?

```js
var str = "www.webmail.meusite.com/foo.webm",
    ext = str.replace(".webm", ".mp4");

console.log(ext); // -> "www.mp4ail.meusite.com/foo.webm"    (-Caramba!)
```

---

Tem que usar uma [expressão regular](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/) para evitar isso:

```
/\.webm$/i
```

- `\.webm` - Casa à cadeia literal `".webm"`.
- `$` - [Cifrão](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#boundaries) que corresponde o fim da cadeia.
- `/i` - **i**gnorar maiúsculas/minúsculas.

#### Código

```js
function alternarExt(value) {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a"),
        regex, ext, a;

    if (value == 0) {
        regex = /\.mp4$/i;
        ext = ".webm";
    } else if (value == 1) {
        regex = /\.webm$/i;
        ext = ".mp4";
    }
        
    // Substituir os links
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        a = links[i];
        a.href = a.href.replace(regex, ext);
        a.textContent = a.href;
        //console.log(a.href);
    }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="ext" value="0" id="opt-webm" onchange="alternarExt(value);" checked="checked">
  <label for="opt-webm">.mp4 -> .webm</label>
  <input type="radio" name="ext" value="1" id="opt-mp4" onchange="alternarExt(value);">
  <label for="opt-mp4">.webm -> .mp4</label>
</form>

<ul>
  <li><a href="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/monstros_sa_2.webm">https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/monstros_sa_2.webm</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/madagascar_2.webm">https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/madagascar_2.webm</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/big_buck_bunny.webm">https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/big_buck_bunny.webm</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/procurando_dory.html">https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/procurando_dory.html</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.webmail.com/foo.webm">https://www.webmail.com/foo.webm</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

- Alternativamente pode usar a seguinte expressão regular para casar qualquer extensão:

  ```
  /\.[a-z0-9]{1,5}$/i
  ```

Comment: Legal que tenha sido útil

Comment: @Diego pode fazê-lo com a informação contida nesta resposta. O que é relevante é efectivamente substituir o link.

Comment: Ok, entendo sua postura no seu modo de ver e interpretar. Mas não era bem uma lista com todos formatos sendo alternado de `webm` para `mp4` e vice-versa. O que buscava era examente como dei a resposta. No caso estou usando a minha solução. No entanto, a sua resposta me chamou a atenção sobre o detalhe da _cadeia de caracteres_ ter o conjunto "webm" e/ou "mp4" em sua formação. Resultando assim, num possível erro, senão fazer o uso da expressão regular para tratar a(s) _strings_.

Answer (score 1):

Segue uma resposta sólida pelo o *método* `replace`, que é mais prático para o objetivo. Veja:

```js
function baixar(arquivo) {
    var get = document.getElementById("download").getElementsByTagName('a');

    var ext = document.getElementById("mp4");

       for(var i in get) {
         var vid = get[i];
         vid.href = arquivo;
         ext.href = vid.href.replace(/\.webm$/g, '.mp4');
       }
}
```

```html
<a href="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/monstros_sa_2.webm" onclick="baixar(this); return false">A</a>
<a href="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/madagascar_2.webm" onclick="baixar(this); return false">B</a>
<a href="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/big_buck_bunny.webm" onclick="baixar(this); return false">C</a>
<a href="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/repositorio/procurando_dory.webm" onclick="baixar(this); return false">D</a>

<hr>

    <span id="download">
        <a id='mp4'>MP4</a> &nbsp; | &nbsp; <a id='webm'>WEBM</a>
    </span>
```

## Explicação

Tive que criar outras variáveis, para aplicar o que [andrepaulo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/55959/andrepaulo) sugeriu - o *método* `replace` .

São elas, as variáveis: `ext` e `vid`.

E partindo do argumento de [Mariano](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/53463/mariano), sobre [expressão regular](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/). Fiz a inclusão para evitar erros.

Aplicamos o *método* `replace` para atualizar as propriedades do objeto `RegExp` global.

```
replace(/\.webm$/g, '.mp4');
```

Para mais detalhes, compare o **antes** e o **depois**:

**Antes**

```
function baixar(arquivo) {

    var get = document.getElementById("download").getElementsByTagName('a');

    for(var i in get) {
         get[i].href = arquivo; 
    }
}
```

**Depois**

```
function baixar(arquivo) {
    var get = document.getElementById("download").getElementsByTagName('a');

    var ext = document.getElementById("mp4");

    for(var i in get) {
            var vid = get[i];
            vid.href = arquivo;
            ext.href = vid.href.replace(/\.webm$/g, '.mp4');
    }
}
```

O código é relativamente limpo e dispensa comentários.

Comment: Sugestão de interface: utilize `radio button` ao invés de `link` para que o usuário saiba se está baixando em **mp4** ou **webm**

Answer (score 0):

Acredito ser nessa parte, se entendi direito o que você quer fazer.

você pode usar o método `replace` das strings no javascript.

```
href = href.replace('.webm','.mp4');
```